# Supplying extra context to binding in windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have an MVVM model that contains two pieces of data, a value (it contains multiple ones, but I will bind to one at a time) and a display context. The display context is more of a formatting string. Now I am trying to bind the value in a view while using that display context to format it correctly.

I have tried using a value converter, but I was unable to send both fields to it. I tried Binding without a specific property, so that I get the whole model in the value converter but this had two issues:
1. Notifications stopped when the values changed
2. I did not have a good way of identifying which property we were binding to.

I can solve this by having a smarter property on the model that did the formatting, but that requires doubling the number of values and gets the model involved in presentation.

So my question is: what is the ideal way to solve this cleanly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this problem by encapsulating the value and the context into a single property and splitting it up in the value converter. This allowed me to keep the notification working, but required the addition of an extra type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have problems accessing your formatting string from the converter. I think that having formatting string (which relates to data representation) in the model layer is not exactly MVVM way. For me, you should put it into your view model. Then you could pass it like a parameter to the converter through the data binding.

Here's the example of how you do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Address, Converter={StaticResource AddressToShortOneLinerAddress},ConverterParameter={Binding YourFormattingString}}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
```

Pay attention to `ConverterParameter` attribute. You could bind it to the view model's property, which holds formatting string. Then you will receive it as a `object parameter` in the `Convert` call:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

Does it help? Or have I completely missed your point?

**EDIT:**
Okay, since previous example don't actually work, here's another approach. The idea is basically to bind the whole `DataContext`, and in converter cast it to your view model type, and get the formatting string from there. Not as elegant, but should work. Here's the sample code, XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AddressToShortOneLinerAddress}, TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
```

... and the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var viewModel = value as MyViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        string format = viewModel.FormattingString;
        return ...;
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Notice how I missed out the `Path` property on `Binding` expression in XAML. Such syntax means we're binding to the whole object, not to one of its properties.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do. However, this syntax does not work. I get an System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException exception
Message: Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.ConverterParameter'
Inner message: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

I believe I've read somewhere that this is not possible because the parameter property is not a dependency property.

Comment: Hmm, I was *mostly sure* I did this before. Let me check my older projects and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, but your second solution is basically what I described in my second paragraph in the original question. Do you have a way of avoiding the two drawbacks I listed?

Comment: Re issue 1: can you be more specific? What are you doing to make things stop working? Re issue 2: obviously there's no way to identify a property you bind to, since you don't bind to a property. If you bind whole view model to different UI objects, you can use different converters for different UI objects.

Comment: In point (1) I was referring to property changed notifications. My whole point of binding is to keep the view in sync with the model as the data changes. When I tried this, I noticed that the notifications were not handled anymore (the handler was always null).